# Join between 2 tables in MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables in MySQL db like this:

First table:

db.number

```
id     name    id_codes    date
```

And second table:

db.number1

```
id_num   package_id    username     paswword
```

Please help me to find name, username, password when date is bigger then x and `num_package =y`.

With Join or another transaction in MySQL db.

PS
`id_codes` at `db.number` is equivalent with `id_num` at `db.number1`

Comment: What exactly is your problem? This is very, very basic. Read the first pages in a SQL book or tutorial and you'll be able to write this query.

Comment: Is `num_package` supposed to be `package_id`?

Answer (score 1):

Is it like this way?

```
SELECT 
T1.name,
T2.username,
T2.password
FROM
number T1
INNER JOIN number1 T2
ON T1.id_codes = T2.id_num
WHERE
T1.date > '2017-05-10' AND
T2.package_id = 'y'
```

Comment: Thanks  @fortune for your answer but is not helpfull for may case i dont know why!

Answer (score 0):

@fortune I used this: like your answer but I modify

```
SELECT 
T1.name,
T2.username,
T2.password
FROM
number T1
INNER JOIN number1 T2
ON T1.id_codes = T2.id_num
WHERE
T1.date > '2017-05-10' 
and T2.package_id = 'y'
```

And this giving me the result that I want.

Comment: oh i thought num_package is the count. My mistake :-)

Comment: Thanks bro @fortune for your help!